# Accessing protected members of derived class with CRTP

Tags: c++, friend, crtp, friend-function

I'm using CRTP, and I have a problem with accessing the protected members of derived class.

Here is example, close to my code:

```
template< typename Self>
  class A {
  public:
      void foo( ) {
          Self s;
          s._method( s); //ERROR, because _method is protected
      }

  protected:
      virtual  void _method( const Self & b) = 0;
  };

class B : public A< B> {
protected:
    void _method( const B & b) {}
};
```

I understood, that I must use **friend** keyword. But I can't understand where to put it in class **A< Self>**. I know that I could make **void _method( const B &b)** public in **B**, but I don't want to do it. Using any keywords in **B** is impossible for me either!

Comment: Put `friend class A<B>;` in `B`.

Comment: Using any keywords in B is impossible for me.

Comment: Why is that? It works here -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/954e7d10d6e1de89

Comment: In my code I may not know all the possible derivations. And I can't order people who derives it to friend from this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. Thanks for answers. I just need to change this line:

```
s._method( s); //ERROR, because _method is protected
```

to

```
( ( A< Self> &) s)._method( s);
```

And it works! http://ideone.com/CjclqZ

Answer (score -1):

```
template< typename Self>
  class A {
  public:
      void foo( ) {
          Self s;
          s._method( s); //ERROR, because _method is protected
      }

  protected:
      virtual  void _method( const Self & b) = 0;
  };
  template< typename Self>
class B : public A< Self> {
protected:
    void _method( const Self & b) {}
};
```

Do it this way; In your Class A _method is pure virtual and you have to override it in Class B.